# Unable to access Apache Vhost

Tags: apache, ubuntu, dns, vhosts

I'm running apache through a clean Ubuntu server VM on Parallels for Mac.  I have it set up following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04)

But when I try to access it from my mac, I get no response.  Ping returns a response, but not viewing the page in chrome.

Here is my [vhost file ccminecraft.com.conf](https://pastebin.com/Nr8cPPbU)

I also tried putting in

```
192.168.1.108 ccminecraft.com
192.168.1.108 www.ccminecraft.com
```

into my hosts file on my mac, but that didn't work.  nslookup returns that it's searching on google's DNS, which both my mac and router are configured to use. But shouldn't it be going to 192.168.1.108 instead of doing a DNS lookup?

Comment: Your configuration file looks fine for the most part minus some other directive info but not required. You may want to look into your networking settings for the VM. If you can't ping the VM guest from your host machine there's a problem networking wise.

Answer (score 0):

Try telneting the port 80 on your ip@ 
`telnet 192.168.1.108 80` if it doesn't respond you need to reconfigure your firewall or disable it.

```
service iptables stop
systemd --> systemctl stop firewall
```

Before usig DNS try with ip@ so in : 
`ServerName` put `yout_ip@` if it works you need to disble the adapter that link you to the internet and just let VM adapter enabled